# datepicker in mvc3 with razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I have two datepicker in my view one for "From" and other for "to".
I want when "from" selected date less than "to" should disable.
and also please guide me how to format the view of datePicker

```
<div>
    From:
    <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
    To:
    <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
</div>


$(function() {
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        highlightWeek: true,
        onSelect: function(selected) {

            $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "mindate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you post at least the code of your view?

Comment: $(function () {
        $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            highlightWeek: true,
            onSelect: function (selected) {

                $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "mindate", selected)
            }
        });
        $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        });

    });

Comment: <div>
                    From:
                    <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
                    To:
                    <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
                </div>

Comment: Please add your code to your post and put it in code block.

Comment: "I want when "from" selected date less than "to" should disable"  What do you want to be disabled?

Comment: In "To" dates less than selected "From " date should disable

Comment: I want when when user select "From" date then dates lesser than selected date in "From", should be disable in "To".

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        buttonImage: '../../Images/DatePicker.jpg',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        buttonText: 'Select date:',
        firstDay: 1,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        showAnim: 'fadeIn',
        onSelect: function () {

            var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate') || new Date(); // Selected date or today if none
            var max = new Date(min.getTime());
            max.setMonth(max.getMonth() + 12 * 10); // Add one month
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker('option', { minDate: min, maxDate: max });

        }
    });
});


$(function () {
    var min = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker('getDate')
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        buttonImage: '../../Images/DatePicker.jpg',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        buttonText: 'Select date:',
        firstDay: 1,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        showAnim: 'fadeIn',
        onSelect: function () { $(this).trigger("onchange", null); }
    });
});
```